# foreach php is getting only first value , and not looping

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach

foreach  is getting only first value , and not looping

```
        $all =TwitchApi::streams($options);

   foreach ($all['streams'] as $streams){
        $stream = new streams;
        $stream->stream_id = $streams['channel']['_id'];
        $stream->game = $streams['channel']['game'];
        $stream->service = 'twitch';
        $stream->viewers =$streams['channel']['views'];
        //$stream->save();
        var_dump($all['streams']);
    }
```

when i var dump ($all['streams']) i get this :

```
{
"_total": 16042,
"streams": [
    {
        "_id": 26962439136,
        "game": "Hearthstone",
        "broadcast_platform": "live",
        "community_id": "",
        "community_ids": [],
        "viewers": 16589,
        "video_height": 1080,
        "average_fps": 60,
        "delay": 0,
        "created_at": "2017-12-12T08:56:11Z",
        "is_playlist": false,
        "stream_type": "live",
        "preview": {
            "small": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_thijshs-80x45.jpg",
            "medium": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_thijshs-320x180.jpg",
            "large": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_thijshs-640x360.jpg",
            "template": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_thijshs-{width}x{height}.jpg"
        },
        "channel": {
            "mature": false,
            "status": "Thijs - Ixlid OTK Malygos Druid, New Kobold Decks ALL DAY",
            "broadcaster_language": "en",
            "display_name": "ThijsHS",
            "game": "Hearthstone",
            "language": "nl",
            "_id": 57025612,
            "name": "thijshs",
            "created_at": "2014-02-17T20:50:47.402453Z",
            "updated_at": "2017-12-12T11:05:42.423142Z",
            "partner": true,
            "logo": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/thijshs-profile_image-d1855265a6df68d1-300x300.png",
            "video_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/7a63e8a30c5bed72-channel_offline_image-1920x1080.png",
            "profile_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/dc9694614e363b35-profile_banner-480.png",
            "profile_banner_background_color": "",
            "url": "https://www.twitch.tv/thijshs",
            "views": 32597794,
            "followers": 418260,
            "broadcaster_type": "",
            "description": "Hello, i am Thijs,21 years old and a gamer from The Netherlands. I am a professional Hearthstone player. I'm currently streaming 4-5 days a week. I hope you have fun with my stream!"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": 26962042192,
        "game": "Overwatch",
        "broadcast_platform": "live",
        "community_id": "",
        "community_ids": [],
        "viewers": 13101,
        "video_height": 1080,
        "average_fps": 60,
        "delay": 0,
        "created_at": "2017-12-12T06:58:30Z",
        "is_playlist": false,
        "stream_type": "live",
        "preview": {
            "small": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_sodapoppin-80x45.jpg",
            "medium": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_sodapoppin-320x180.jpg",
            "large": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_sodapoppin-640x360.jpg",
            "template": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_sodapoppin-{width}x{height}.jpg"
        },
        "channel": {
            "mature": true,
            "status": "Not in my closet.",
            "broadcaster_language": "en",
            "display_name": "sodapoppin",
            "game": "Overwatch",
            "language": "en",
            "_id": 26301881,
            "name": "sodapoppin",
            "created_at": "2011-11-22T04:40:56.75883Z",
            "updated_at": "2017-12-12T11:04:12.64584Z",
            "partner": true,
            "logo": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/sodapoppin-profile_image-10049b6200f90c14-300x300.png",
            "video_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/sodapoppin-channel_offline_image-2040c6fcacec48db-1920x1080.jpeg",
            "profile_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/sodapoppin-profile_banner-1c050aa5aed3558d-480.png",
            "profile_banner_background_color": "",
            "url": "https://www.twitch.tv/sodapoppin",
            "views": 179453317,
            "followers": 1657156,
            "broadcaster_type": "",
            "description": "Wtf do i write here? Click my stream, or i scream."
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": 26962643024,
        "game": "",
        "broadcast_platform": "live",
        "community_id": "",
        "community_ids": [],
        "viewers": 12000,
        "video_height": 1080,
        "average_fps": 60,
        "delay": 0,
        "created_at": "2017-12-12T10:00:18Z",
        "is_playlist": false,
        "stream_type": "live",
        "preview": {
            "small": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_yogscast-80x45.jpg",
            "medium": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_yogscast-320x180.jpg",
            "large": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_yogscast-640x360.jpg",
            "template": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_yogscast-{width}x{height}.jpg"
        },
        "channel": {
            "mature": false,
            "status": "JINGLE JAM 2017 DAY 12! - OFFICE CAM",
            "broadcaster_language": "en",
            "display_name": "Yogscast",
            "game": "",
            "language": "en",
            "_id": 20786541,
            "name": "yogscast",
            "created_at": "2011-02-27T20:19:01.423136Z",
            "updated_at": "2017-12-12T11:03:58.616948Z",
            "partner": true,
            "logo": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/db623728431d29c3-profile_image-300x300.png",
            "video_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/35edb9a8141ab1c3-channel_offline_image-1920x1080.png",
            "profile_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/yogscast-profile_banner-61f0e8b351336524-480.png",
            "profile_banner_background_color": "#d7d7d7",
            "url": "https://www.twitch.tv/yogscast",
            "views": 69681161,
            "followers": 661492,
            "broadcaster_type": "",
            "description": "Hello! And welcome to The Yogscast! Streaming every day at 5PM BST! Minecraft and multiplayer comedy gaming with a drunken dwarf, a handsome spaceman and the rest of the Yogscast family!"
        }
    }
```

but when i var_dump($streams)  i am getting only the first value like this :

```
{
"_id": 26962440352,
"game": "Grand Theft Auto V",
"broadcast_platform": "live",
"community_id": "2b86280e-e3fd-4b7c-b1e1-ee8b2ed2818f",
"community_ids": [
    "2b86280e-e3fd-4b7c-b1e1-ee8b2ed2818f"
],
"viewers": 998,
"video_height": 720,
"average_fps": 60.0282485876,
"delay": 0,
"created_at": "2017-12-12T08:56:41Z",
"is_playlist": false,
"stream_type": "live",
"preview": {
    "small": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_alexclick-80x45.jpg",
    "medium": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_alexclick-320x180.jpg",
    "large": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_alexclick-640x360.jpg",
    "template": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_alexclick-{width}x{height}.jpg"
},
"channel": {
    "mature": false,
    "status": "[Faily V] Alex Murphy #46",
    "broadcaster_language": "fr",
    "display_name": "Alexclick",
    "game": "Grand Theft Auto V",
    "language": "fr",
    "_id": 89284114,
    "name": "alexclick",
    "created_at": "2015-04-23T11:39:25.363072Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-12-12T11:33:48.955085Z",
    "partner": true,
    "logo": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/c9ab63d5f7e93091-profile_image-300x300.png",
    "video_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/bfad7c61a33b3644-channel_offline_image-1920x1080.png",
    "profile_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/72bfa9debe329e2f-profile_banner-480.png",
    "profile_banner_background_color": "",
    "url": "https://www.twitch.tv/alexclick",
    "views": 1920535,
    "followers": 49971,
    "broadcaster_type": "",
    "description": "Streamer & Youtubeur mais surtout triple champion du monde de deltaplane de salon. Toutes les infos et stream sur http://www.alexclicktv.fr"
}
```

}

after this loop i have a return  but it does not make any difference  because i am dumping the data before reaching the return statement 
what's wrong ?

Comment: `$stream = new streams;` suppose to be outside the loop I guess

Comment: tried that also , same thing

Comment: `$all = json_decode($all, true)` before the loop. Can you edit your question to contain a complete JSON string? Yours is trimmed at the end.

Comment: i wanted to do that :) but the response iam getting is more then a 100 so i just toke  a sample of 3 from it i did not want to make it too missy :) anyway add the closing at the end and it should be fine

Comment: beacause you have created new object into foreach loop every time it creates new and assign another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer guys :)

```
        $all =TwitchApi::streams($options);
    $clean[] = $all['streams'];
    //dd($clean['0']['1']['game']);
    for ($idx = 0; $idx < 100; $idx++){
        //print_r($idx);
        $stream = new streams;
        $stream->stream_id = $clean['0'][$idx]['channel']['_id'];
        $stream->game = $clean['0'][$idx]['channel']['game'];
        $stream->service = 'twitch';
        $stream->viewers =$clean['0'][$idx]['channel']['views'];
        $stream->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You named the second variable inside of the foreach loop `$streams`, while in the body of the loop you are referencing `$stream`.

Comment: yes , because $stream ref to the database , which $streams ref to the array of $all['streams']

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$all =TwitchApi::streams($options);
      $all = json_encode($all);
     function objectToArray( $object )
      {
        if( !is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ) )
        {
            return $object;
        }
        if( is_object( $object ) )
        {
            $object = get_object_vars( $object );
        }
        return array_map( 'objectToArray', $object );
    }
$depth = 512;
$options = 1;
$result = json_decode ($json, $assoc, $depth, $options);
$result = objectToArray($result);
var_dump($result["_total"]);
```

What happens is, first the all is converted to JSON and then it converted into Array and then the value can be fetched from the array.

Comment: why would i want to encode and then decode it ???? beside i did not understood which value to put inside ? to get the result that i want

Comment: the stream which you used returns an array of JSON format. To properly convert to JSON we are using encode and then we need to decode inorder to convert into array. And then foreach the desired value can be fetched. That's it

Comment: what to use inside of this ? $something = $value["Your array variable"];
please tell me with my variables

Comment: for example the $value["_id"]; The output will be 26962440352

Comment: Figured out, need to add some extra lines. See the above answer.

Comment: Send me your email id.. I'll ping you the codes if you need.

Comment: The Function ObjectTOArray converts the stdclass object to array. 100% working